# How to test jQuery fadeOut / fadeIn with rspec

Tags: jquery, rspec

I try to figure out how to test the jQuery fadeIn / fadeOut behaviour with rspec. I do have the following scenario:

On the page there is a checkbox. If the checkbox is ticked, an additional input field gets shown. If not, the input field is hidden. The animation I use to show and hide the input field are the jQuery fadeIn / fadeOut effect.

In my feature test I would like to check that when the checkbox is ticked, the input field is shown on the page, and if it is not checked, the input field is not shown. The issue is now, that when i call check('#checkbox_recurring') within my rspec and then test straight away, if the input field is on the page, it will probably fail, as the jQuery animation has not yet been completed.

How does one test such a scenario?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to get jQuery fadeIn to work, but I used toggle. I hope this is ok.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  #input {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
 </style>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
<input type='checkbox' id='check'>Toggle</button>
<input id = 'input' placeholder = 'name'></input>
<script>
$( "#check" ).click(function() {
  $( "#input" ).toggle( "slow" );
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You need to use ruby `sleep (time)` to wait until jQuery/AJAX elements finish. Here is a link explaining [Watir wait methods](http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/).

I used Rspec and Watir-Webdriver to automate the browser. Here is a quick snippet, this could be cleaner, but it should give you some direction for what you are trying to accomplish.

```
require 'rspec'
require 'watir-webdriver'


describe 'fade' do
  before(:all) do
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
    @browser.goto('file:///C:/Users/bashir.osman/Desktop/test.html')
  end
  it 'checks fade' do
   puts "so...#{@browser.input(:id, 'check').exists?}"
   @browser.input(:id, 'check').click
   sleep 1
   exists1 = @browser.input(:id, 'input').visible?
   if exists1 == false
     puts 'Currently input is not visible'
     puts 'Will click input again'
     @browser.input(:id, 'check').click
     sleep 1
     exists2 = @browser.input(:id, 'input').visible?
     exists2.should == true
   end
  end
end
```

This is what the test does:

1. Clicks on the checkbox
2. Checks if the `#input` is visible. This should return false.
3. Clicks on the checkbox again
4. Checks if `#input is visible. This should return true

I would not use `.exists?` as this will always return true because the element exists in the DOM. `present?` returns true if the element exists and is visible on the page. `visible?` returns true/false depending on if the element is visible.

Comment: This indicates, that the test needs to know about the timeout used by the UI to fadeIn / fadeOut the input field - which is from my point of view not good (as any change to the time would break the test).

Comment: You could dynamically change the time variable whenever you update the timeout used in your UI. For more information about Watir/Wait please go to this link - https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/wiki/AJAX-and-waiting-for-elements